Auto/Manually Generation of Work Order Through Maintenance plan
We are using the maintenance plan for generating work orders (WO) and service appointments (SA) on a recurring pattern, such as generating an SA every 14 days. We are able to generate the WO/SA, but currently, all future SAs are generated at once.
According to our use case, we need each WO/SA to be generated 2 days prior to the SA date, instead of generating all future WOs/SAs at once. We are also using a window start date and window end date, which is useful, but the main issue is the creation of all future WOs/SAs.
Is it possible to adjust this? Please advise.
Thank you.
